# Referencing a function from another drl file in a separate maven project

Tags: java, maven, drools

I have multiple maven projects with DROOLs drl files in them. I would like to put things like helper functions in a central location and then have the drls in other projects be able to use them, but it isn't working.

The common project is a maven dependency in the other projects. I can prove this is working because I have access to the facts that I define in the common project, but I don't have access to functions.

1. I initially tried creating a file called:
   helperfunctions.drl and put the functions directly in the file thinking they would be available without any imports when building and they are not found.
2. I then tried wrapping the functions in a declare HelperFunctions end, but this syntax doesn't work.
3. Finally, I tried changing the file to HelperFunctions.java and did public class HelperFunctions and made all of the methods static. Then in the other project drls I imported using the namespace com.myproject.common.

I am out of options, is there anything else I can try or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about what you've attempted, but Java code from a dependency (your point #3) can be invoked from the rules if you have the Jar on your classpath.

Imagine you have your project set up as follows:

```
|-rule-utils (project name)
|-- src\main\java\com\mycompany\common\HelperFunctions.java
|--pom.xml
```

And you have defined some utility function `public static void doSomethingUseful()` in your HelperFunctions class.

In your other project where your rules exist, you can include your `project1` jar as a dependency, possibly as follows in your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>rule-utils</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
</dependency>
```

And then you can import and use HelperFunctions and its `doSomethingUseful` method as you would any other Java code in your drl:

```
import com.mycompany.common.HelperFunctions;

rule "Example rule"
when
then
  HelperFunctions.doSomethingUseful();
end
```

In my experience, it's pretty common to invoke third-party utility code this way, for example the Apache commons' utility classes like `StringUtils` and `CollectionUtils` (though more often on the left hand side than in the consequences.)